# Name an Exception For UNIT_TESTCASE while uploading to AzureCloud BlobStorage

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-blob-storage

Name an Exception For UNIT_TESTCASE while uploading to AzureCloud BlobStorage .

My Code is ,

```
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a container.
 CloudBlobContainer container = 
 blobClient.GetContainerReference("myblogcontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = 
container.GetBlockBlobReference("WeekendChamps.jpg");

// Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
 using (var fileStream = 
 System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Bliss\Downloads\WeekendChamps.jpg"))
 {
 blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
 }
```

Comment: "Name an exception" ?? See [ask]

Comment: I think that there r more than an exception ! So I put some. if u understand the question , please answer @bommelding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the try catch block catch the [StorageException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.storageexception?view=azure-dotnet) and within the catch block you can process the exception to get the RequestInformation and the StorageExtendedErrorInformation.

There are various exception codes defined for Blobs in the [BlobErrorCodeStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.protocol.bloberrorcodestrings?view=azure-dotnet) class. You can do a switch case on the errorcodes or you can try to match any specific error codes that you require.

Comment: Here StorageException Refers to which error in that code. For eg : Mismatch of container Name. @Aravind

Comment: ContainerNotFound is what you will get in this case since that particular container name was not found (because of mismatch in the name)